# Convert from CSV to Nested JSON with array in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, csvtojson

I'm trying to convert from csv to complex nested json. Below is how my CSV looks like

**Sample csv**

title,section_id,content,expected

"Test case1",1234,"Test step1","Expected Result1"

"Test case1",1234,"Test step2","Expected Result2"

"Test case1",1234,"Test step3","Expected Result3"

**Expected output**

```
  'title': 'Test case 1',
  'section_id': 1234,
  'custom_steps_separated': [
    {
      'content': 'Test step1',
      'expected': 'Expected Result 1'
    },
    {
      'content': 'Test step2',
      'expected': 'Expected Result 2'
    },
    {
      'content': 'Test step3',
      'expected': 'Expected Result 3'
    }
  ]
}
```

**Code so far**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('testcases.csv')
df['custom_steps_separated'] = df[['content','expected']].to_dict('records')
out = df[['title','section_id','custom_steps_separated']].to_json(orient='records', indent=4)
jsondict = json.loads(out)
for i in range(0,len(jsondict)):
 print(list(jsondict)[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for your case. You can use **groupby**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'title':["Test case1","Test case1","Test case1"],
                               'section_id':['1234','1234','1234'],'content':["Test step1","Test step2","Test step3"],'expected':["Expected Result1","Expected Result2","Expected Result3"]})

df.groupby(['title','section_id']).apply(lambda x: x[['content','expected']].to_dict('records'))
       .reset_index()
       .rename(columns={0:'custom_steps_separated-Data'})
       .to_json(orient='records')
```

the output what i got is,

```
[
    {
        "title": "Test case1",
        "section_id": "1234",
        "custom_steps_separated-Data": [
            {
                "content": "Test step1",
                "expected": "Expected Result1"
            },
            {
                "content": "Test step2",
                "expected": "Expected Result2"
            },
            {
                "content": "Test step3",
                "expected": "Expected Result3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Cool.. Please acknowledge the answer. Thank you